# What are the measurements of the different Lego instruction booklets?

Tags: technic, instructions, city, friends

I've noticed that there are at least three different sizes (eg 7.8"x5", 4"x5.8" and 7"x8"). Are there other sizes?

Comment: Are we counting all the way down to single page instruction sheets?

Then we have the wire spiral-bound instructions for the Imperial Star Destroyer (10030) that are roughly 12"x16" and over 200 pages...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? As phrased the answer to your question is "yes, there are other sizes".

Comment: There are many sizes. It would be difficult or impossible to list them all.

Comment: I'm planning to help organise a friend's stash of Lego as a surprise, and I know he has different types including City, Technic and Exoforce.  I'm wanting to plan ahead so I have the right size boxes.

Comment: Moz - my question is 'What are the measurements of the different Lego instruction booklets?"

Comment: @Skippy without knowing what sets your friend has there's no way to tell what size boxes you'd need. Even within a theme the instruction booklet size varies considerably. I put my instructions into binders, using letter-size page protector sheets. Some of my instructions are taller than the sheet, that is, they are bigger than 8.5"x11". Not to mention the Architecture and Ideas books which are square-bound like a paperback novel and quite thick (and all different sizes).

Comment: The latest Technic books are over 1cm thick, but fit into an A4 box

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes.

There are over 30 types, depending on box size. Some of them look more like books. Some of them are impractical, and haven't been reintroduced since their debut.