# What is the maximum size of Lego instruction booklets?

Tags: instructions, size

I am preparing a shelf and, given that LEGO instruction booklets these days are often more like actual little books than the small booklets we had as children, a section of that shelf will be reserved for LEGO instruction booklets.

Therefore, I am interested in the maximum size (width and, in particular, height) that instruction booklets come in so far. To start, I'm assuming a height of 26cm (that's the largest booklets I have here right now), but maybe there are even taller ones?

Note that this question is similar to [*What are the measurements of the different Lego instruction booklets?*](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/what-are-the-measurements-of-the-different-lego-instruction-booklets), however, I am not asking for a list of all sizes, just for the maximum size I would have to reckon with. Therefore, as opposed to the other question, it is also irrelevant to me which sets are (or will be) there in particular - one level in the shelf that is tall enough to fit in all instruction booklets (standing upright, like books) will last for a while, and if that level (let's say, of 1m in width) gets filled, it's time for another solution, anyway.

EDIT: Note that I am based in Europe and, in case instructions come in different sizes for different parts of the world, it can be reasonably assumed that all of the sets will be bought in Europe.

Comment: This reminded me that the first file/folder/wallet I ever had was for storing exactly those little booklets.

Comment: Assuming that all sets bought in Europa are European sets is a bad idea. I just bough the 1960's Mustang model (10265) last week in a toy-store in The Netherlands and it was de US version (easily identified because the US version have the parts-count printed on the box.)

Answer (score 7):

While there are multiple sizes of instructions and lack of database with dimensions my answer is based on personal observation.

Looking at the stash of my instructions from multiple sets (including several largest Technic models) I can state that the largest dimension I have is of A4 paper size, which is 210 x 297 mm. I'd like to note that this is for Europe based sets. There might be different sizes for other markets as LEGO provides two options for their instructions online - optimized for A4 as well as Letter sized paper.

**Edit 1.** As masterX244 pointed out in the comments Star Wars UCS sets may have bigger instructions. [This review on Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/30610/millennium-falcon-unboxing) of SW UCS set with highest number of parts (75192 Millennium Falcon) says instructions are 42 x 29 cm in size. This is very close to A3 paper size, which is twice the size of A4.

Picture below, from the very same review by Brickset, shows the instruction relative to side of the [box](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=75192-1) (45 x 39 cm).

[image]

**Edit 2.** JPhi1618 found that UCS Star Destroyer 10030 set has a booklet that is slightly larger - 43 x 30 cm (landscape orientation, including the spiral)

Comment: Thank you, I incorporated the quirk about regional sizing into the question.

Comment: Get one of the large SW UCS sets. those yield a roughly A3 sized ringbound book.

Comment: The old UCS Star Destroyer 10030 has a booklet that is 43cmx30cm (landscape orientation, including the spiral).

Comment: @JPhi1618 you may want to post this as an answer. I could only find there were two versions (glued and spiral bound) but no details on the measurements.

Comment: @Alex, it was really meant to reinforce the measurements of the MF manual you posted as some of the biggest (they are pretty much the same size).  I can say that I measured my booklet, so that's first hand knowledge.