# List of sets with large spiral-bound instructions?

Tags: instructions, set-database

I am looking for instructions similar to those of the 75192 Millennium Falcon, i.e. large-format ring binder instructions. Is there a list of sets that have these? Or a database from which this information can be derived? Bricklink does have images of the instructions, but doesn't specify the binding type.

It would be nice if such a list existed. If you know some sets with this binding type, please also mention those.

I own the 75192, 75252 and 10188 instructions, all are nice examples of this type.

Comment: I have checked the [BrickLists](https://brickset.com/bricklists) section of Brickset but cannot find anything either. Most databases cover only parts and stickers so it may be difficult to find something like this.

Comment: [This question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/13407/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-lego-instruction-booklets) says that the 10030 instruction book is even larger (size, not weight) than the 75192. [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?I=10179-1&name=Millennium%20Falcon%20-%20UCS&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BUltimate%20Collector%20Series%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%204/5/6%5D#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}) even has a comment on the spiral-bound instructions of the 10179 Millenium Falcon. Spiral-bound seems to be the correct term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some manual search, I found only a small number of sets that definitely have spiral-bound instructions. All of them are from the Star Wars theme and almost all of them are UCS models. This is the list so far:

10030 Imperial Star Destroyer - UCS (either glued or spiral-bound)
10179 Millennium Falcon - UCS
10188 Death Star
10221 Super Star Destroyer - UCS
75159 Death Star - UCS
75192 Millennium Falcon - UCS (2nd edition)
75252 Imperial Star Destroyer - UCS (2nd edition)
21005 Fallingwater

Please comment or edit if you are aware of other sets.

The following sets were confirmed to not have spiral-bound instructions:

31203 World Map
10276 Colosseum
71043 Hogwarts
10256 Taj Mahal
71741 Ninjago City Gardens
75978 Diagon Alley

Comment: Perhaps this needs to be converted to Community Wiki?

Comment: @jncraton What is the intention for adding sets that don't have spiral-bound instructions?

Comment: Probably that they are large sets that you would expect the extensive instructions would be spiral bound... I find it useful information. One can hypothesize that spiral binding is something reserved for starwars UCS and similar sets...

Comment: I checked the sets with over 5k parts out of curiosity. I wanted to share the results so that anyone else looking at this wouldn't duplicate the effort.

Comment: @jncraton That makes sense. Only very large sets will have spiral binding. So far, this seems to be a Star Wars exclusive thing.

Comment: Large sets and large building instructions are not necessarily correlated. For example the building instructions for the Taj Mahal model are relatively short, because nearly all the model is highly repetitive   - most of it consists of four identical subsections.

Comment: @alephzero That might be true but smaller sets will certainly not have spiral-bound instructions. So focussing on large sets makes sense. Maybe the seven sets we found so far are the only ones.

Comment: Also, if this is supposed to become one of these huge list answers where everyone adds their examples into, that is probably the singlemost appropriate use case for making the post Community Wiki.

Comment: @Rauy I doubt that this list will become much longer. A visual search on Bricklink didn't reveal any further ring-bound instructions.